# Android Java OpenGL Conversion

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

When you program with java in android does it get converted to OpenGL to be able to show it on Screen or what does it do?

and if it does which version of OpenGL does it use?

PS: I know you can use OpenGL as renderer when using java but this is a question of what happens in software/hardware to show it on screen.

If i'm not clear enough tell me and i will try to explain myself better, Thanks again

does canvas api get implicitely translated to opengl?

Comment: "When you program with java" as in anything? Unless its 3d then probably not. For 2d it probably uses some native methods unless you specifically code in OpenGL.

Comment: yes as in anything else and those native methods are what i want to know :D

Comment: Andon if you put that as an answer i will close it thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Android is layered on top of EGL, but the graphics stack has multiple paths as illustrated below <sup>(diagram courtesy of Alison Chaiken, she-devel.com):</sup>

[image: Android Graphics Stack vs. Linux]

The overall architecture is described in more detail than you would probably ever want to know [here](http://source.android.com/devices/graphics.html). "SurfaceFlinger" is analogous to X11 in the Android world and EGL takes the place of GLX.